# How to render/retrieve "field[]" in django forms?

Tags: django, html, django-forms

I'm trying to use array field in django 
to dynamically add fields using javascript like user clicks on button and a new field appear

However I cannot figure out how to make django to render field as "field[]" name, neither I can't get that field value in django view.

I tried to manually create the fields in the view,

```
  <input type="text" name="image_url[]" id="id_image_url">

  <input type="text" name="image_url[]" id="id_image_url2">
```

But in the view I can only get the last value of image_url,

```
>>>request.POST["image_url[]"]
>>u'url2'
>>>form.cleaned_data["image_url"]
>>>u''
```

I was thinking in FormSets but it doesn't seems to be what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all the inputs with `name="image_url[]"`, use [`getlist()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist).

```
request.POST.getlist("image_url[]")
```

Note that you only need the square brackets because they are in the html input. Django doesn't do anything different because they are included in the name - you could change the html to `name="image_url"` and the view to `request.POST.getlist('image_url')` and it would still work.

If you want to use Django forms, then you would probably have to write a [custom field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#creating-custom-fields).

Comment: Yes I think the square brackets are a php convention